# vue large form with multiple components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a large form that I have split into different components. The main or parent component will have the submit button while the child components are section off the different categories. What I need to know is when the user clicks the submit button, how can I grab the values from the input fields of the child components and have them verified in the parent component before sending it all to the server.

Here is a code example of what I am trying to say. The main will just render the other components and the submit button. I am not sure where or how I could do the field validation first and than submit it all to the server.

main.vue

```
                <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
                <table class="table" style="background: #ffffff">
                <tr>
                    <td id="app1" >
                        <applicant1></applicant1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="table" style="background: #ffffff">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="app2" >
                            <applicant2></applicant2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="table" style="background: #ffffff">
                    <tr>
                        <td><button
                                type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-primary">
                            Process License Request
                        </button><!--onClick="stripfields()-->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                class="btn btn-secondary"
                                @click="resetForm()">
                            Reset Form
                        </button>
                        </td>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Applicant1 from './applicant1.vue'
import Applicant2 from './applicant2.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'applicant1': Applicant1,
    'applicant2': Applicant2
  },
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetForm () {
      console.log('Reseting the form')
      //.....clear all the form values
    },
    onSubmit (e) {
        console.log(e)
        //........get values form applicat 1 and 2 components
    }
  },

}
</script>

<style scoped>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    }
</style>
```

This are the 2 extra components

applicant1.vue

```
    <template>
    <div style="margin: 20px;">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="title">
                    <b>Applicant 1  Information</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <span color="#000080"><b>First</b>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span color="#000080"><b>Middle</b>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span color="#000080"><b>Last</b>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    Name:
                </td>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <input type="text" name="applicant1FirstName" v-model="applicant1.FirstName" maxlength="60"
                    id="firstname">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="applicant1MiddleName" v-model="applicant1.MiddleName" maxlength="60"
                    id="middlename">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="applicant1LastName" v-model="applicant1.LastName" maxlength="60"
                    id="lastname">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">Street Address:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="applicant1StreetAdd" v-model="applicant1.StreetAdd" maxlength="30" id="streetadd">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    City:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="applicant1City" v-model="applicant1.City" maxlength="20" id="city" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    State, Zip:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name = "applicant1[GState]" id="gstate" v-model="applicant1.GState">
                        <option label="-" value="">-</option>
                        <option v-for="state in states" v-bind:value="state.Code">{{ state.Code }}</option>
                    </select>,
                    <input type="text" name="applicant1Zip" size="9" v-model="applicant1.Zip" maxlength="12" id="zip" >
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    County Residing:
                </td>

                <td colspan="3">
                    <select name = "applicant1County_dropdown" id="county_dropdown" v-model="applicant1.County_dropdown">
                <option label="-" value="" disabled>-</option>
                <option v-for="county in counties" v-bind:value="county">{{ county }}</option>
                </select>
                 &nbsp;&nbsp; Or &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" name="applicant1County" v-model="applicant1.County" maxlength="15" id="county" >
                </td>
            <tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'applicant1',
  data () {
    return {
      applicant1: {
        FirstName: '',
        MiddleName: '',
        LastName: '',
        GroomMaName: '',
        Title: '',
        StreetAdd: '',
        City: '',
        State: '',
        Zip: '',
        County_dropdown: '',
        County: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

applicant2.vue

```
    <template>
    <div style="margin: 20px;">
        <div class="divSpace">
            <h4>Applicant 2 nformation</h4>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><span color="#000080" size="2"><b>First</b></span></td>
                <td><span color="#000080" size="2"><b>Middle</b></span></td>
                <td><span color="#000080" size="2"><b>Last</b></span></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="FirstName" v-model="applicant2.FirstName" maxlength="60"
                           id="firstname" ></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="BMiddleName" v-model="applicant2.MiddleName" maxlength="60"
                           id="middlename"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="LastName" v-model="applicant2.LastName" maxlength="60"
                           id="lastname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    Street Address:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="StreetAdd" v-model="applicant2.StreetAdd" maxlength="30" id="streetadd" >
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    City:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="City" v-model="applicant2.City" maxlength="20" id="city" 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    State, Zip:
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <select name = "State"
                            id="bstate"
                            v-model="applicant2.State">
                        <option label="-" value="">-</option>
                        <option v-for="state in states" v-bind:value="state.Code">{{ state.Code }}</option>
                    </select>,
                    <input type="text" name="Zip" v-model="applicant2.Zip" size="9" maxlength="12" id="zip" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="lables">
                    County Residing:
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <select name = "applicant2" id="dropdown" v-model="applicant2.County_dropdown">
                        <option label="-" value="" disabled>-</option>
                        <option v-for="county in counties" v-bind:value="county">{{ county }}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'applicant2',
  data: function () {
    return {
      applicant2: {
        FirstName: '',
        MiddleName: '',
        LastName: '',
        BStreetAdd: '',
        BCity: '',
        BState: '',
        BZip: '',
        BCounty_dropdown: '',
        BCounty: '',
      }
    }
}

</script>
```

I am still new to vuejs so forgive me if I am not explaining this all to well. Thank you

Comment: Probably you should look into this: [Vue Guide: Send Messages to parent component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events)

Comment: Hi, it is not recommended  to do what you are trying to do. It will couple components together and make the whole thing less maintainable. Keep the data in the parent and pass what is needed for each children. That is a common pattern in Vue and it will help a lot.

Comment: This is so wrong in many levels and beats the idea of "Components". Why would you want the parent component do the verification?

Comment: Julian Paolo Dayag: actually I would do the validation right in the child component, not parent commponent., I did not explain that correctly, sorry. I am just trying to than grab all the information once the button is clicked in the parent component.to send to the server side.